# reference in Montgomery/ Zippin

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, locally-compact-groups

In a paper, the authors use the reference [M–Z, Theorem in 4.13] where [M-Z] denote the book 
D. Montgomery and L. Zippin, Topological Transformation Groups. Interscience
Publishers, New York–London, 1955.

Unfortunately, I have no access to the edition of 1955 of this book. I would be very
grateful if you would help me to know the theorem.

Comment: [tag:reference-request] should not be used as a standalone tag, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part 4.13 has 3 pages, here are the scans:
[188](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNU1T.png), [189](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SfXp.png), [190](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNZBP.png).

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a generous man.

Comment: It's 4 years later and I needed this exact same result.  Thanks once again!